# How can I change the registered name in Windows 7 to my own?

Tags: windows-7, ownership

how do I change the registered name in Windows 7 to my own name?

Answer (score 7):

*Via a registry tweak:*

- Press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `regedit`.  Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Navigate to:

  > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion

[image]

As seen above, you can see the `RegisteredOrganization` and `RegisteredOwner`.  Double-click either to change the registered owner/organization!

To confirm changes, just type `winver.exe` in the Start search box or in the Run Command dialog box, and you should be able to see your changes without a restart.

*Source:* [Quick Tip: Change the Registered Owner in Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/quick-tip-change-the-registered-owner-in-windows/)