# Where can I get name of the person who registered Windows and his organization?

Tags: windows, forensics

Having access to an image of a system which I can't boot up on a virtual machine, how could I figure out who registered Windows and its organization? I can use Autopsy to access the files, but don't know in which file it's stored such information.

I've tried in **setupact.log** which contains information about the actions done during installation, but I wasn't able to get this information. I need also to find the Product ID (not the product key), but it isn't in that file either.

Comment: Your best bet is probably extracting the registry hives.  [This link will show you which values hold the information]( http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/quick-tip-change-the-registered-owner-in-windows/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the registered name in Windows 7 to my own?](http://superuser.com/questions/280284/how-can-i-change-the-registered-name-in-windows-7-to-my-own)

Answer (score 0):

This is usually going to be found in the registry by searching for "**ProductID**" however, there is no definitive key since it's going to be inside of a hexvalue (e.g.: 4932487236ABDEF0000) but it will be inside of:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Products\$HEXKEY
```

The value(s) will tell you the product key, RecCompany, RegOwner, Contact (if entered on install) and so forth.

It's apparent you have little forensics experience if you didn't understand my initial answer. You can mount that image as a [virtual system](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) and do it, bring it into EnCase and do it, or even into [Digital Forensics Framework](http://www.digital-forensic.org/) and extract it. There are plenty of options to use to read the image.

Comment: I know it can be  found there, but did you read what I wrote? I can't boot the partition, it is a forensic image.

Comment: There is no need to boot from something to read from it. Example: you can read just fine from an USB pen drive without booting from it. So just boot from another place and read-only access a [copy of] the disk.

Comment: you didn't understand my question I think, but never mind, I got this already using Windows Registry Recovery and loading the SOFTWARE file.